# how to show stopwatch in windows form without using timers

Tags: c#, winforms

i am new bee in this field.
i am using a timer in my windows form which fetches data from database in a fixed interval. Now i want that my timer remail same but i need to show a stopwatch running every second on my screen.
Is there any way to do it? the code is here.....

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Timer _timer;
    int count = 0;
    // The last time the timer was started
    private DateTime _startTime = DateTime.MinValue;

    // Time between now and when the timer was started last
    private TimeSpan _currentElapsedTime = TimeSpan.Zero;

    // Time between now and the first time timer was started after a reset
    private TimeSpan _totalElapsedTime = TimeSpan.Zero;

    // Whether or not the timer is currently running
    private bool _timerRunning = false;
    public Form2(String UserName)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 1000;
        _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        label4.Text = UserName; 

    }


    private void richTextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        count = count + 1;
        var timeSinceStartTime = DateTime.Now - _startTime;
        timeSinceStartTime = new TimeSpan(timeSinceStartTime.Hours,
                                          timeSinceStartTime.Minutes,
                                          timeSinceStartTime.Seconds);

        // The current elapsed time is the time since the start button was
        // clicked, plus the total time elapsed since the last reset
        _currentElapsedTime = timeSinceStartTime + _totalElapsedTime;

        // These are just two Label controls which display the current 
        // elapsed time and total elapsed time

        label3.Text = timeSinceStartTime.ToString();
        String str1, str2;
        SqlDataReader rd1, rd2;
        SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=216.218.224.238;Database=chatapp;Uid=chatappuser;pwd=1234@ChatAppUser;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;");
        // SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=;Password=;Connection Timeout=600");
        Con.Open();

        rd1 = new SqlCommand("select top 1 Chat from chat where  where email ='" + label4.Text + "'order by id Desc", Con).ExecuteReader();
        rd1.Read();
        str1 = rd1["Chat"].ToString();
        rd1.Close();
        rd2 = new SqlCommand("select top 1 UserInitial from chat where email ='" + label4.Text + "' order by id Desc", Con).ExecuteReader();
        rd2.Read();
        str2 = rd2["UserInitial"].ToString();
        rd2.Close();
        if (str1 != str2)
        {
            SqlDataReader rd3, rd4;
            rd3 = new SqlCommand("select top 1 UserInitial from chat  where email ='" + label4.Text + "'order by id desc", Con).ExecuteReader();

            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + " <br /> " + rd3.Read();
            rd3.Close();
            rd4 = new SqlCommand("Update top 1 chat set Chat = UserInitial  where email ='" + label4.Text + "'order by id desc", Con).ExecuteReader();
            rd4.Read();
            rd4.Close();
            Con.Close();
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!_timerRunning)
        {
            // Set the start time to Now
            _startTime = DateTime.Now;

            // Store the total elapsed time so far
            _totalElapsedTime = _currentElapsedTime;

            _timer.Start();
            _timerRunning = true;
        }
        else // If the timer is already running
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            _timerRunning = false;
        }
        SqlDataReader rd5;
        SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=216.218.224.238;Database=chatapp;Uid=chatappuser;pwd=1234@ChatAppUser;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;");
        // SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=;Password=;Connection Timeout=600");
        Con.Open();
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "<br />Me:" + richTextBox2.Text;
        rd5 = new SqlCommand("Update chat set UserInitial ='" + richTextBox2.Text + "' order by id Desc where email ='" + label4.Text + "'", Con).ExecuteReader();
        rd5.Read();
        rd5.Close();
        Con.Close();
    }


    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _timerRunning = false;

        // Reset the elapsed time TimeSpan objects
        _totalElapsedTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
        _currentElapsedTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
        label3.Text = _totalElapsedTime.ToString();  
        MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
        count = 0;
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.....

Comment: Just curious, but why do you do 3 calls to the database with virtually the same query.  You could do `select top 1 chat, userinitial from chat...` and populate `str1`, `str2` and `rd3` in one shot.

Comment: You also need to look up and use parameterized sql.  This sql is ripe for a SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Inside the event OnDoWork you can add your logic to fetch data from database and update your interface every fixed interval. 
You can start and stop, please the the link for more details on how to use it.

**EDIT**

I made a small demo to demonstrate the use of the background worker. Anyway you should improve your logic for retrieving data from database.
Note: depending on how fast your query runs, if they are slow you should do this actions, retrieving data and showing the stopwatch, on different threads, otherwise your stopwatch value will be wrong.

```
private bool _running;
private BackgroundWorker _bw;
private Stopwatch _watch;
private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BwOnProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void BwOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        while (_running)
        {
            if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
            else
            {                    
                // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                String str1, str2;
                SqlDataReader rd1, rd2;
                SqlConnection Con =
                    new SqlConnection(
                        "Data Source=216.218.224.238;Database=chatapp;Uid=chatappuser;pwd=1234@ChatAppUser;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;");
                // SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=;Password=;Connection Timeout=600");
                Con.Open();

                rd1 =
                    new SqlCommand(
                        "select top 1 Chat from chat where  where email ='" + label4.Text + "'order by id Desc", Con)
                        .ExecuteReader();
                rd1.Read();
                str1 = rd1["Chat"].ToString();
                rd1.Close();
                rd2 =
                    new SqlCommand(
                        "select top 1 UserInitial from chat where email ='" + label4.Text + "' order by id Desc",
                        Con)
                        .ExecuteReader();
                rd2.Read();
                str2 = rd2["UserInitial"].ToString();
                rd2.Close();
                if (str1 != str2)
                {
                    SqlDataReader rd3, rd4;
                    rd3 =
                        new SqlCommand(
                            "select top 1 UserInitial from chat  where email ='" + label4.Text + "'order by id desc",
                            Con).ExecuteReader();


                    var value = rd3.Read();
                    rd3.Close();

                    if (richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        richTextBox1.BeginInvoke(
                            new MethodInvoker(() => richTextBox1.Text += richTextBox1.Text + " <br /> " + value));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + " <br /> " + value;
                    }
                    rd4 =
                        new SqlCommand(
                            "Update top 1 chat set Chat = UserInitial  where email ='" + label4.Text +
                            "'order by id desc", Con).ExecuteReader();
                    rd4.Read();
                    rd4.Close();
                    Con.Close();
                }

                Thread.Sleep(1000); //sleep 1 second

            }
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
        if (label3.InvokeRequired)
        {
            label3.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => label3.Text = _watch.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString()));
        }
        else
        {
            label3.Text = _watch.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString();
        }
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _running = true;
        _watch = new Stopwatch();
        _watch.Start();
        _bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        //start the timer
        _timer.Start();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        _bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        _bw.DoWork += BwOnDoWork;
        _bw.ProgressChanged += BwOnProgressChanged;

        // instantiate the timer
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 1000;
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;

    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _running = false;
        _bw.CancelAsync();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
       //dispose resources
         _bw.CancelAsync();
        _bw.Dispose();
        _watch.Stop();           
        _timer.Dispose();
    }
```

To remove the `Thread.Sleep(1000)` you can keep your timer just for the stopwatch on the form thread and assign the updating chat work to the background worker. This way the time elapsed will be more accurate.

Comment: thank you very much for the code...i am gonna try it and are you sure that it will not be affact my timer??

Comment: and i noted one thing also... every button click method is also affecting my timer... i aslo find out solution for this problem

Comment: If you use the background worker to query the database and update your interface, then on the form thread it will run only that timer which is updating the elapsed time. So keep the timer just for updating the elapsed time.

Comment: I just made it like demo, I don't know exactly when you want to start updating the interface and when to show the stopwatch. Just update it according to your needs. Glad to know that you found the solution.

Comment: as i told u timer is also waiting when button_click is fired. What is the solution for that???

Comment: Use a System.Timers.Timer, this one is running on a different thread and it will not wait when you press a button. The disadvantage is that you have to use Invoke when updating the label on the form.

Comment: yes... that is exactly the problem i am facing. Please give me a better solution for it.

Comment: I updated the answer, please check. As an advice do not perform any consuming operation directly on the form's thread, if you do so then your application will not respond until that operation is not completed, and it will freeze.

Comment: it shows correct time. but i want to update my label regularly after every second so that it seems to be a correct timer....

Answer (score 5):

You can use [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to get the amount of time `Elapsed`

From MSDN :

> Provides a set of methods and properties that you can use to
>   accurately measure elapsed time.

**Step 1:** create a `StopWatch` variable as class level variable.

**Step 2:** call the `Start()` method, whenever you want to start the counting.

**Step 3:** for every `timer_tick` event you can take the Totalseconds elapsed by usig `stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds`.

Try This:

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  label1.Text = watch.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString();
}
```